# Fastest way to reposition sublist in python

Tags: python, list

What is the fastest way to reposition a sublist from a list in Python?

Let's say we have a list `L = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`, now I want to take `[c,d,e]` and put it after `g` in the list. How can I do this *fast*?

Edit:
In other words I would like to write a function that:

1. extracts a sublist L_sub of length *n* from L, leaving L_temp
2. insert the items of L_sub at a given position *i* into L_temp

The main question I guess is how to insert a list into list as fast as possible.

Comment: How do you know that c,d,e are the items you want to move?  Are they fixed-position, or are you checking values?

Comment: What if the sublist overlaps the insertion point?

Comment: This is not possible, @lazyr's answer also prevents this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume OP wants to do this inplace.

The key to making the operation fast is to minimize the creation of lists and the shortening/lengthening of lists. This means we must strive to always do a 1:1 assignment of list indices, so no `L[i:i] = L[a:b]` and no `L[a:b] = []`. Using loops with `insert` and `pop` is even worse, because then you shorten and lengthen the list many times. Concatenating lists is also bad because you first have to create one list for each part and then create larger and larger concatenated lists, once for each `+`. Since you want to do this "inplace", you'd have to assign the generated list to `L[:]` in the end.

```
    # items:   0 | 1   2   3 | 4   5   6   7 | 8   9
    #            a   span1   b     span2     c
    # pos:       1           4               8

    # Result:
    #          0 | 4   5   6   7 | 1   2   3 | 8   9
    #            a     span2         span2   c
```

Lets first make an observation. If `a = start`, `b = end = start + length`, and `c` is the insert position, then the operation we wish to do is to cut at the `|` markers and swap `span1` and `span2`. But if `b = start` and `c = end` and `a` is the insert position, then we *also* want to swap `span1` and `span2`. So in our function, we just deal with two consecutive segments that must be swapped.

We can't wholly avoid making new lists, because we need to store overlapping values while moving stuff around. We *can* however make the list as short as possible, by choosing which of the two spans to store to a temporary list.

```
def inplace_shift(L, start, length, pos):
    if pos > start + length:
        (a, b, c) = (start, start + length, pos)
    elif pos < start:
        (a, b, c) = (pos, start, start + length)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Cannot shift a subsequence to inside itself")
    if not (0 <= a < b < c <= len(L)):
        msg = "Index check 0 <= {0} < {1} < {2} <= {3} failed."
        raise ValueError(msg.format(a, b, c, len(L)))

    span1, span2 = (b - a, c - b)
    if span1 < span2:
        tmp = L[a:b]
        L[a:a + span2] = L[b:c]
        L[c - span1:c] = tmp
    else:
        tmp = L[b:c]
        L[a + span2:c] = L[a:b]
        L[a:a + span2] = tmp
```

Kos seems to have made an error in his timings, so I redid them with his code after correcting the arguments (calculating `end` from `start` and `length`), and these are the results, from slowest to fastest.

```
Nick Craig-Wood: 100 loops, best of 3: 8.58 msec per loop 
vivek: 100 loops, best of 3: 4.36 msec per loop
PaulP.R.O. (deleted?): 1000 loops, best of 3: 838 usec per loop
unbeli: 1000 loops, best of 3: 264 usec per loop
lazyr: 10000 loops, best of 3: 44.6 usec per loop
```

I have not tested that any of the other approaches yield correct results.

Comment: The previous version you posted worked, this one does not: x = range(10); inplace_shift(x, 2,3,0) returns [0, 1, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], this should be [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

Comment: This produces incorrect results. If I call `inplace_shift(range(10), 3, 2, 6)` I get `[0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. It SHOULD produce `[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 9]`

Comment: @Colt 45: This is just a matter of calling convention. Should `pos` be  interpreted as where to insert _before_ "cutting" the slice to move, or _after_? If you prefer the latter, insert `if pos > start: pos += length` as the first line of the function. I prefer the former since then inserting at the end a list `L` is always the pos `len(L)` -- there's no need to take the length of the slice into account.

Comment: @Colt 45: Then again, with my calling convention you have to watch out so you don't "paste" to a position inside the slice you're going to move, so it's really down to taste.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with python substrings

```
def subshift(L, start, end, insert_at):
    temp = L[start:end]
    L = L[:start] + L[end:]
    return L[:insert_at] + temp + L[insert_at:]

print subshift(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'], 2, 5, 4)
```

`start` and `end` refer to the position of the substring to cut out (end is non-exclusive in the usual python style.  `insert_at` refers to the position to insert the sub string back in again *after* it has been cut out.

I think this will be faster than any solution with iteration in it if the substrings are more than a character or two in length as nice optimised C code is doing the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

Let's check what we got so far:

Code

```
def subshift(L, start, end, insert_at):
    'Nick Craig-Wood'
    temp = L[start:end]
    L = L[:start] + L[end:]
    return L[:insert_at] + temp + L[insert_at:]

# (promising but buggy, needs correction;
# see comments at unbeli's answer)
def unbeli(x, start, end, at): 
    'unbeli'
    x[at:at] = x[start:end]
    x[start:end] = []

def subshift2(L, start, length, pos):
    'PaulP.R.O.'
    temp = pos - length
    S = L[start:length+start]
    for i in range(start, temp):
        L[i] = L[i + length]
    for i in range(0,length):
        L[i + temp] = S[i]
    return L

def shift(L,start,n,i):
    'vivek'
    return L[:start]+L[start+n:i]+L[start:start+n]+L[i:]
```

Benchmarks:

```
> args = range(100000), 3000, 2000, 60000

> timeit subshift(*args)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.43 ms per loop

  > timeit unbeli(*args)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 631 ns per loop

> timeit subshift2(*args)
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop

> timeit shift(*args)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop
```

Comment: You seem to be testing two different cases. In subshift and unbeli, you're using start, end as arguments, which means the slice you're moving is empty with the arguments you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate inplace solution:

```
def movesec(l,srcIndex,n,dstIndex):
    if srcIndex+n>dstIndex: raise ValueError("overlapping indexes")
    for i in range(n):
        l.insert(dstIndex+1,l.pop(srcIndex))

    return l


print range(10)
print movesec(range(10),3,2,6)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    # orginal
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 9]    # modified
```

Comment: @unbeli: It seems to be. Try commenting out `return l` and call this with a list. Compare the list before and after. Isn't that 'inplace'? I just have the `return l` as a convenience...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
>>> L[7:7] = L[2:5]
>>> L[2:5] = []
>>> L
['a', 'b', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h']
```

Comment: Wouldn't this misbehave if you'd try to insert 5:7 at 2? The second L[2:5] would then refer to a different place than the first L[2:5]

Comment: Try `L = range(5)` and subshift `[3:5]` to `0`; expected ` [3, 4, 0, 1, 2]` actual `[3, 4, 0, 3, 4]`

Comment: This appears to be the fastest approach from what's posted so far, but the indices in the second assignment need to be offset to also work in the case I've mentioned.

Comment: @Kos you don't have to be too stupid with this. Just calculate the indicies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def shift(L,start,n,i):
    return L[:start]+L[start+n:i]+L[start:start+n]+L[i:]
```